# Can I simplify the following Haskell lambda?

Tags: haskell

I want to simplify the following lambda using composition or some higher order magic,

```
(\a b -> if (b) then (not a) else a)
```

but I couldn't think of a clever way. Could you please help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want composition?

Comment: in my opinion this looks simple lambda expression. We can rewrite but depends what flexibility you want in the expression.

Comment: Hey @SumitMahamuni I am just a beginner, and I am curious to know if there is a clever way to write it.

Comment: Riffing on other answers, but just defining a function `xor a b = if b then not a else a`  looks fine.  If you don't need it all over the place, you can just stick it in a `where` declaration to the current function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another user pointed out, this is an example of `xor`, so how would we define this function?

If the inputs are equal, the result is false.
If the inputs are not equal, the result is true.

```
\x y -> x /= y
```

Edit: The commentor is correct, my bad! The definition I gave previously does not work.

Comment: `xor x x` doesn't check that the `x`s are the same, it just raises a conflicting definitions compile-time error.

Answer (score 12):

Let's look at the truth table:

```
   a    b      f
------------+------- 
False False | False
False True  | True
True  False | True
True  True  | False
```

That's interesting!  `f` is `True` whenever the inputs are not the same. Hmm......

Comment: It is xor, but I don't know how to implement it cleverly :(.

Comment: @Rohit, great!  BTW, in Haskell it's spelled `/=`.  And you can write the `(\a b -> a /= b)` as simply `(/=)`; it's a notation that works for all infix operators.